# truffle + npm exception

Tags: npm, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am getting the following exception in Chrome console screen when I start my frontend app. Can you help me how to figure out the issue

```
index.ts:261 Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="bets(uint8)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.1)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:261:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:273:1)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:429:1)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (index.ts:400:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I forgot to post the contracts in truffle

```
migrate --reset
```